# Using pyinstaller with two python environments

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to pack one .py file into .exe. I have two Python3 environment on my WIN10 64-bit computer. One is from **Anaconda** and **the other is Python3-32bit** which is installed separately. This .py file is produced by **Anaconda Python environment.**
After I installed pyinstaller, I set the environment variable PATH like this:`

> PATH=PATH;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Python35-32\Scripts;

However, when I enter `pyinstaller file.py` it throws me lots of warnings:
[image]

It seems that `pyinstaller` searches dependencies in Python35-32's lib folder rather than Anaconda's. How can I make it searche dependencies under Anaconda's lib folder?
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install pyinstaller using pip or using (ana)conda? if so, check whether pip is the python3-32bit or the anaconda one with:

```
pip -V
```

This will tell you if pip, and hence pyinstaller, was installed on the 32-bit interpreter, hence why it's looking in that particular folder.

solution would be to install pyinstaller using conda or within the anaconda IDE. Probably would need to uninstall pyinstaller from python3-32bit

Comment: Hi @dzman. I installed `pyinstaller` on python3-32bit first. Then installed it again using `conda install`. My `pip -V` gives me 'pip 10.0.1 from c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.5)'. What should I do next?

Comment: I think the problem is that running pyinstaller from the prompt is defaulting to the python32 version, so maybe uninstalling that python 32 one using pip?

Comment: You are right. I uninstalled the python3-32bit pyinstaller and then the pyinstaller is searching within Anaconda's scripts folder. Does this means that if I want to pack another .py file provided by python3-32bit, I must unistall Anaconda's pyinstaller and install python3-32's pyinstaller again?

Comment: You should be able to just run the conda's pyinstaller to pack that py file. Pyinstaller however will use the modules from anaconda. If you want to use dependencies installed in python35-32, the thing to do is create a virtual environment for the python35-32 using `python -m venv test-env`and then activate that virtual environment, install pyinstaller and all the required modules, then run pyinstaller using that virtual environment