# exe file works in Anaconda Prompt window but not in Windows command line

Tags: python-3.x, windows, matplotlib, anaconda, pyinstaller

My python code include tkinter and matplotlib. I create a .exe with pyinstaller. When I run the exe I get this message:

```
appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:623:
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable
was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.  
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
```

When I run it with Anaconda Prompt, the message appears and my interface run normally. If I run it with Windows command line (or double clik) the message appears but no interface appears.

If I suppress matplotlib import, the exe works with Windows command line too. The issue is clearly caused by matplotlib, but I have no idea how to solve it. Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Using: Python 3.7.9 Pyinstaller 3.6 Matplotlib 3.2.2

Comment: I guess it has to to with PATH or PYTHON_PATH. Maybe try `pip show matplotlib` in both Anaconda and Windows Command Line. I guess they differ because Anaconda has its own installtion paths.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I don't succeed in showing the paths with windows command line. If you are right, do you have any idea for fixing the issue ?

Comment: You should at least be able to show the paths. Try `echo $PATH` and `echo $PYTHON_PATH` in Anaconda Prompt and in Windows Settings show all Environment Variables.

Comment: Maybe you should also check if you can bundle your depencies into your .exe file. Would be good to know how you created the .exe

Comment: Ok thank for your answers. We suppose that the path is different. I create my exe with a simple command line `pyinstaller mycode.py`. Maybe there is some option that can solve my problem ?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388833/using-pyinstaller-with-two-python-environments). Maybe try a virtual environment before creating the exe. 
Or you could try the [--onefile](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyi-makespec.html?highlight=onefile#description) option.

Comment: Thank for the link. I've already tried the option --onefile and it does not work... I will try to generate a virtual environement. I will give a feedback later.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here :
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4968#issuecomment-662075970

The issue comes from pyinstaller and not from missing options or environment